# "'m164' is not recognized as an internal or external command", building OpenSSL using VS 2013 Developer Command Prompt

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, build, nmake

I'm following the guide to building OpenSSL for Visual Studio here: http://developer.covenanteyes.com/building-openssl-for-visual-studio/

Apparently all I need is the latest version of the OpenSSL source code, Active Perl or Strawberry Perl, and Visual Studio 2010. I'm using 2013, but I thought I'd give it a try anyways. When I get to the nmake command, I get the error shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I guess this is because I'm using VS 2013 instead of 2010? Does anyone know of a way to correct this issue, or does anyone know of a guide I can use to get OpenSSL working in VS 2013? I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error 6/26/16.  Apparently m164.exe is an assembler on AMD boards (I'm using Intel, where it is ml.exe). I was unable to work around it. But the 32 bit version doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: Passing the build tool the "no-asm" argument seems to work as well. Not sure what repercussions this might have down the line though.

Answer (score 1):

**Here what worked for me:**
Apparently this issue was caused on my side because of missing environment variables settings. Per OpenSSL documentation I installed `Microsft Platform SDK`, and in addition, on my machine I have `Microsoft Visual Studio 2013`, but still had to setup the evironment variables, as described below:

1. Set environment variable for `Visual-Studio` (2013 in my case) by running the `vcvars64.bat` batch file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat`
2. *[OPTIONAL]*
   On my machine the condition was that some of the binaries where already built, *but with the wrong environment variables*, so I first had to thoroughly clean the build environment by running the following command:
   `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak reallyclean`
3. Then I re-started the build process as described by the `INSTALL.W64` file:

   1. `perl Configure VC-WIN64A`
   2. `ms\do_win64a`
   3. `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`
   4. `cd out32dll`
   5. `..\ms\test`

After this all was working!

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 of the answer by @PazO helped me eventually figure out a solution to this problem, while the answer by @Hugh helped me figure out what was wrong in the first place.

The root problem here is that you should not be looking for "m**1**64.exe" but instead "m**l**64.exe". Note the lowercase L instead of the number 1.

The link in the question is no longer available, so I don't know whether the typo was in another library or created manually, but fixing that should theoretically solve that issue in that scenario.

The following is additional information I think might be useful to others receiving this same message.

Now for getting your environment set up correctly from the start. If you have installed Visual Studio, I do not know from which version it started doing this, but it puts shortcuts into your start menu for launching a console with the environment pre-configured.

For the following, replace `[YEAR]` with the installed version of Visual Studio, such as `2019`.

There is a generalized developer console with this environment for command prompt or powershell, respectively titled `Developer Command Prompt for VS [YEAR]` and `Developer PowerShell for VS [YEAR]`.

The shortcuts folder can be found by opening Run and executing `shell:common start menu`, then navigating to `Programs\Visual Studio [YEAR]\Visual Studio Tools\VC\`.
Alternatively, the full path will be like `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio [YEAR]\Visual Studio Tools\VC\`. In this directory are shortcuts for specific architectures (that end up running the respective `vcvars` `.bat` file). Additionally, the folder above this holds the "Developer" consoles mentioned in the previous paragraph.

For completion's sake, those `vcvars` `.bat` files can—as of now in the Community version of Visual Studio—similarly be found in the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\[YEAR]\Community\Auxiliary\Build\` directory.